Proving Radial Symmetry rigorously for Laplace's Equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$
I was reading in Evan's PDE book that Laplace's equation is radially symmetric. Simple enough I thought. However, this becomes non-trivial for me when I move to $n$-dimensions for the following reasons. I thought that the definition of radially symmetric meant that there is only dependence on $r$, however, this doesn't make too much formal sense. What I found on the internet is the following
"An operator acting on functions on an euclidean space is radially symmetric, if the operator is rotationally invariant. That is, under a change of coordinates along a rotation, the operator is invariant."
Then again, simple enough I thought until I realised I had no idea what the rotation in $S^{n+ 1}$ looks like in general. Of course I can look it up, do a change of variables, cry for a couple of hours, and get the final result but I had a realisation. Intuitively with the above definition of being radially symmetric, what we want is to make sure all operators depend on $r$ only. So I just need to find a parametrisation, not necessarily a rotation, such that when I change coordinates, there is only radial dependence. One such parametrisation that is easily derivable is
\begin{align*}
  x_1& = r \cos \theta_1 \\ 
 x_2 &  = r \sin\theta_1 \cos \theta_2   \\ 
  \vdots  &  \\ 
  x_{n-1} &  = r \sin\theta_1 \sin(\theta_2)\dots \sin_{\theta _{n-2}} \cos (\theta_{n-1}) \\
  x_{n} &  = r \sin\theta_1 \sin(\theta_2)\dots \sin_{\theta _{n-2}} \sin(\theta_{n-1}).
  \end{align*}
Doing so ends up working out transforming into the equation into an ode in terms of the radius implying that all solutions are radial. However, I am not quite sure if this implies Laplace's equation is radial given the above definition.
My question: Do I have the wrong definition of being radially symmetric? Whenever you think of showing radial symmetry what do you use? Have I confused my self?

The symmetry is not 'radial': it's spherical: radius fixed in euclidean $\mathbb R^n $ the Laplacian is the dul of the canonical square of the tangent basis of $S^{n-1}.$ wrt. to the volume $n-1$ form.

Hi, thank you for the comment @RolandF. So when we say an operator has a symmetry due to some geometry, then this means that it is in the dual space of the tangent basis? Also, if so, how does one go about proving that. Is it sufficient to parameterise as above?

Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be represented by orthogonal matrices, which are matrices $O$ satisfying $O^T = O^{-1}$. The claim that Laplace's equation $\Delta u = 0$ is rotationally invariant means that if $u \colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\Delta u = 0$, then for any orthogonal matrix $O$, $v(x) := u(Ox)$ satisfies $\nabla v = 0$ as well. (This is actually Problem 2 in Ch.2 of Evans.)
More generally, you can show that if $O$ is an orthogonal matrix and you define $v(x) = u(Ox)$ as above, then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ we have
$$\Delta v(x) = \Delta u(Ox),$$ which formalizes the claim "under a change of coordinates along a rotation, the operator is invariant."

Hi, thank you for this. Could you clarify the following for me: If I am able to make a parameterisation in which I can show there is only radial dependence, i.e. I am making the equation an ode purely radial, then any rotation doesn't change anything. Does this imply the result without having to construct the rotation outright?
